# React: Converting mongoDB date to human readable date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, datetime

A document stored in MongoDB has a "createdAt" property, which contains a timestamp. Here we have an example of the timestamp:

```
createdAt: 2021-10-26T12:24:33.433+00:00
```

Considering this date is today, how can I reproduce the following behavior?:

- Display this date as "Today at 12:24 PM"
- Tomorrow, display this date as "Yesterday at 12:24 PM"
- From the day after tomorrow and beyond, display it as "26/10/2021 at 12:24 PM"

I tried using the JavaScript's Date instance to compare both strings but I got into some trouble trying to convert the strings properly. I was wondering if there's any library that could ease the process or some conventional way to do it.

Comment: you can use moment.js library

Comment: or [day.js](https://day.js.org/) (similar but not as heavy) library. It will do the string to date processing for you

Comment: Easiest way is to use a third party lib like `date-fns` and use `formatDistance` which is documented [here](https://date-fns.org/v2.25.0/docs/formatDistance)

Comment: Commenters: Please just add answers with a simple example snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention using React, I assume that you have a Node running there somewhere. Maybe a `create-react-app` backend? I will also assume ESM.

You would achieve something like this with date-fns; see docs at https://date-fns.org/v2.25.0/docs/formatDistance

`$ npm i date-fns` First, install dependency, then test it like below:

```
import formatDistance from 'date-fns/formatDistance'

function TestComponent() {
   const dateStr = "2021-10-26T12:24:33.433+00:00";
   const str = formatDistance(
       new Date(dateStr),
       new Date()
   );
   return <h1>{str}</h1>
}
```